# Firebase user signup with email and send them password via email

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to allow users to sign up to a Firebase website using only their email and phone number.  At a later time, I would like to send them their auto-generated password via email.  Is this possible to do with Firebase Auth or Realtime Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing. You'll have to create the account through the Admin SDK, so in a trusted environment like your dev machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions. There you [call `createUser(...)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) with the email the user entered, the a temporary password that you made up.

You *could* do the same client-side, but in that case the password would be determined from the client too, which wouldn't be secure.

Comment: Is there an easy way to validate whether the email or phone number exists?  I don't understand how to grab the error from the createUser if it is not client side?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but will try to answer. If you want to know if an email is registered, you can call [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchsigninmethodsforemail). For phone number there's no API on the client, but on the server that'd be [`getUserByPhoneNumber `](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getuserbyphonenumber). To verify if an email exists/is correct, send a verification email with: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email

Comment: This is spot on to what I needed. I apologize for my ambiguity. Thank you.